# When editing in block editor, the post/article gets under the floating widgets

Tags: widgets, block-editor

When editing in block editor, the post/article gets under the floating widgets and I am not able to edit that portion of the article which is behind the widget inside block editor. I am attaching a screenshot for better understanding.[image: image of block editor, here the post grid widgets are on top of the diagram in the article]

Comment: Welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange :-)! We love to help. But this sounds like a bug report that should be reported to the involved theme's/plugin's issue queues, not here. Many thanks

Comment: @leymannx thanx da myre